# jquery - remove not working correctly.  src doesnt work with google chrome . what should i do to remove the braces 

Tags: jquery, append, prepend

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // all jQuery code goes here  
    $("li").hover(function(){
        $(this).prepend("<span>(</span>");
    },function(){
        $(this).append("<span>)</span>");
    });
    /*
    function (){
        $("li").remove();
    } 
    */

    $("li.fade").hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(100);
        $(this).fadeIn(300);
    });
 });
 </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="class1"> 
<ul id="1"> 
    <li class="fade" ><a href="server43.hostpoint.ch/~raffael1/web2.roboearth/">What is RoboEarth?</a></li> 
    <li class="fade"><a href="server43.hostpoint.ch/~raffael1/web2.roboearth/motivation/…; <li class="fade"><a href="server43.hostpoint.ch/~raffael1/web2.roboearth/project-scope/… Scope</a></li>              
</ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: it works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/4r2hG/. what browser are you using?

Comment: <div class="class1">
       <ul id="1">
               <li class="fade" ><a
href="http://server43.hostpoint.ch/~raffael1/web2.roboearth/">What is
RoboEarth?</a></li>
               <li class="fade"><a
href="http://server43.hostpoint.ch/~raffael1/web2.roboearth/motivation/">Motivation</a></li>
               
               <li class="fade"><a
href="http://server43.hostpoint.ch/~raffael1/web2.roboearth/project-scope/">Project
Scope</a></li>
               <li class="fade"><a


       </ul>
</div>

Comment: iam using google chrome. checked with safari too. It doesnt work

Comment: Instead of posting your code as comment, just edit your initial question. So that the markup will be parsed correctly!

Comment: NOw it works. but the remove doesnt work correctly.  ps. what should i include in the script src ="";http://jsfiddle.net/g9p7A/2/    @Headshota,@Andi

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing that you want the brackets appear on mouse over, and removed on mouse out.

jquery hover first callback is for the mouse over state, the second for mouse out, thus:

```
$("li").hover(
    function() {
        // mouse over
        $(this).prepend("<span>(</span>");
        $(this).append("<span>)</span>");
        },
    function() {
        // mouse out
        $(this).find('span').remove();
        }
    );
```

Comment: ya exactly. Ya it works now but it doesnt work in my browser or either at http://tulipsworld.weebly.com/code.html . I think some other probs in my code. I uploaded my code at the above link. can you explain what is the error?